# Printing date range in AIX

Tags: shell, date, ksh, aix

I'm trying to print date range in AIX. I'm not able to use 'date' in AIX properly. I've tried some solutions suggested in Stack overflow. Nothing worked. Please find the error and code below. 
I can't download 'GNU'.

```
#!/bin/ksh
startdate=20141030
enddate=20141120

loop_date=$startdate

let j=0
while [ "$loop_date" -ne "$enddate" ]; do
        loop_date=`date   -j -v+${j}d  -f "%Y%m%d" "$startdate" +"%Y%m%d"`
        echo $loop_date
        let j=j+1
done
```

Error: 
date: illegal option -- j
Usage: date [-u] [+Field Descriptors]

Comment: Why did you think there was a `-j` option?

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this.When I investigated little more. I found out, I'm not supposed to use any of the options except '-n', '-u' or '-a' in AIX (man date). I'm wondering is there any other way to print the date range. I've tried to include perl, got below error.  -- Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains.

Comment: I've found similar problem in AIX, but there is no solution to it. [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276598/get-date-1-day-using-aix)

Comment: If you don't have gawk, and you don't have perl, and you don't have Python, and you can't compile a newly-written piece of software in C, you don't have a whole lot of options here. I mean, there are tools that the POSIX spec just isn't complete enough to cover, so sometimes you *need* tools that aren't in the baseline kit.

Comment: Quite a few people was able to download GNU!coreutils, I don't know why OP is unable to do so...

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this. @M. Dogru provided a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
#!/bin/ksh
startdate=$1
enddate=$2
loop_date=$startdate
currentdate=`date +%Y%m%d`

let j=0;

if [[ $startdate -lt $currentdate && $enddate -lt $currentdate ]];then
loop_date=$currentdate
while [[ "$loop_date" -gt "$startdate" ]]; do
loop_date=$(TZ=CST+$j date +%Y%m%d)
   if [[ $loop_date -le $enddate ]];then
      echo $loop_date
   fi
let j=j+24
done
fi

if [[ $startdate -gt $currentdate && $enddate -gt $currentdate ]];then
while [[ "$loop_date" -lt "$enddate" ]]; do
loop_date=$(TZ=CST-$j date +%Y%m%d)
   if [[ $startdate -le $loop_date ]];then
      echo $loop_date
   fi
let j=j+24
done
fi


user@host:/tmp:>ksh test.sh 20150630 20150705 
20150705
20150704
20150703
20150702
20150701
20150630
user@host:/tmp:>ksh test.sh 20170630 20170705 
20170630
20170701
20170702
20170703
20170704
20170705
```